# Python: Install 2.5.5?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Here is the page I found to get 2.5.5:

http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.5.5/

(I need it for Google App Engine.)

All I see is source files, not an installer. I'm not entirely sure how to build them on my windows machine. What do I do? (Open in Visual Studio, build there?) Or is there an installer I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2.5.5 is unfortunately only available as source, but you can get 2.5.4 installers [here](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.5.4/).  If you're just debugging on your local machine for GAE, the differences between 2.5.4 and 2.5.5 won't matter to you.

You can find build instructions for Windows [here](http://www.python.org/dev/faq/#how-do-i-create-a-debug-build-of-python) if you want to build from source.  While they're intended for developers building debug builds, they'll work for you to make a release build as well.

Comment: Sweet now I have three versions of Python on my machine, haha. Is there any reason that certain versions are available as installers and others aren't?

Comment: @Rosarch: Really it's because making installers and testing and qualifying them is a lot of effort, and 2.5.5 was released after 2.6.x was available.  If you were stuck with 2.5.x and couldn't upgrade to 2.6, you likely were in a position where building it yourself was an acceptable compromise.

Comment: IIRC, i also believe that 2.5.5 was a source-only release, so building new binaries that wouldn't behave any differently than 2.5.4's would not benefit anyone.

Comment: @wescpy: it was a source only release (no one has ever said anything otherwise...), but it only contained a security bug fix, not any behaviour changes.  Because the OP is only using it to integrate in GAE on his desktop machine, 2.5.5 is functionally identical to 2.5.4 (obviously you can't control the Python version in GAE deployment).

Comment: @wescpy: It's a little hard to tell what you really intended in your comment, but if you're saying that the lack of functional differences is why there's no binary, that's completely besides the point - security fixes, regardless of functional difference, are very important to move into the field quickly.  In this case it's just a matter of that fix being deployed in an installable form in the 2.6.x tree, so there wasn't a huge motivation to building and testing installers in the 2.5.x tree as well.

Comment: i'm not 100% sure of their motivation, but the core team would've released binaries if they felt that it was necessary. perhaps the securty fixes don't involve PC users. i haven't dug into the python-dev archives to ascertain the reasoning. thanks for the additional comments!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [2.5.2](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.5.2/) instead of 2.5.4.

I started out with 2.5.4 but found that the SDK would fail when sending email using the --smtp_host option. I downgraded to 2.5.2 after finding [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=626), and sending email then worked.

Also, 2.5.2 is the exact version which is used by App Engine in production.